# Execute code in a custom OncePerRequestFilter after all the other OncePerRequestFilter in the spring app

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-oauth2

My spring app is configured with spring security with JWT
When I execute something inside a custom `OncePerRequestFilter` I see

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = null
```

My understanding is JWT uses `OncePerRequestFilter` to set `SecurityContextHolder`
So now my question is how can execute a custom `OncePerRequestFilter` that runs after all other `OncePerRequestFilter` so that I can get SecurityContext as not null?

Little more context I setup my spring app via following spring security config

```
spring.security.resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://test.zitadel.cloud
          jwk-set-uri: https://test.zitadel.cloud/oauth/v2/keys
```

And security config

```
fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
     http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
}
```

I do not have any other OncePerRequestFilter in the app

Comment: you can print all the filters and then add your filter so that is after the correct filter in the chain https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-print-filters